# Swap DIV class on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hover, toggle, hidden

This is what I'm trying to achieve :

2 DIV's, on page load the first DIV is visible, on hover it switches to the second DIV (which is initially hidden).

Both DIV's are the same height and width and are positioned absolutely within the wrapper.

This is what i've got so far, but it's not working properly -

JS :

```
 (function($) { 
 $(".wrap").hover(function() {
 $(".first,.second", this).toggle();
 })
 })( jQuery );
```

CSS :

```
 .wrap {position:relative;}

 .first {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 padding:20px;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 background:green;
 color:white;
 display:block;
 }

 .second {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 padding:20px;
 width:80px;
 height:80px; 
 background:yellow;
 color:blue;
 display:block;
 visibility:hidden;
 }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="first">FIRST DIV</div>
<div class="second">SECOND DIV</div>
</div>
```

Here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W7fzh/) so you can see what's happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use css hover ?

Comment: after switching to another div, and mouseout, do you want to maintain state, or revert back to default?

Comment: @servabat I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @MaulikAnand I'd like it to revert back to the default state.

Comment: in manner of saying :) make it user friendly how a user ll know that hovering is required here u need to give them direction as well :)

Comment: I meant using css :hover property. You set visibility of first div to hidden on hover and the other to visible.

Comment: @servabat No that won't work in this situation. I'm using classes instead of ID's because there are going to be repeating div's with different content on the same page. CSS Hover would change every instance of the classes when hovering over any one of them. That's why I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont Use `visibility:hidden`, instead use `display:none`

```
.second {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      padding:20px;
      width:80px;
      height:80px; 
      background:yellow;
      color:blue;
      display:none;
}
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W7fzh/3/)**

Comment: Ahh you changed the JS too! Ok, that makes sense. Thanks so much Amit ;)