# jQuery Hover not working on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hover, visibility

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351070/swap-div-class-on-hover-with-jquery) about toggling DIV visibility earlier today and received the correct answer which works perfectly as you can see in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56KaB/).

I'm basically trying to toggle div visibility on repeating classes with jQuery hover.

The problem is, I can't get it working on my Wordpress site.

The jQuery just isn't firing at all even though all of the div's and CSS is present and correct. There are no error's being reported in the console at all. It's just not loading this function.

I must be calling it incorrectly!

FYI - WP site is loading jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery.migrate 1.2.1.

The jQuery exactly how it is located in the footer of the site (wrapped due to compatibility mode) :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 (function($) {
   $(".showlist-wrap").hover(function() {
   $(".showlist-artwork,.showlist-info",this).toggle().off("hover");
 });
 })( jQuery );

 </script>
```

The CSS looks like this :

```
 .showlist-wrap {
   position:relative;
   width:293px;
   height:195px;
   background:black;
   margin-right:13px;
   margin-bottom:13px;
   float:left;
   border-radius:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
 }

 .showlist-artwork {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   width:293px;
   height:195px;
   display:block;
 }

 .showlist-info {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   width:293px;
   height:195px;
   display:none;
 }
```

The HTML fires like this :

```
 <div class="showlist-wrap">
 <div class="showlist-artwork"><img src="/image.jpg" /></div>
 <div class="showlist-info">Some Text Goes Here</div>
 </div>
```

Like I mentioned above, the actual CSS is displaying perfectly on the page and everything HTML wise is where it should be. It's just the jQuery not working so the code must be incorrect.

Could somebody show me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: what browser are u using? If u use IE, make sure the mode is greater than IE8

Comment: No IE here, all Mac. Chrome, Firefox & Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is because you're not waiting for `DOM ready` before binding the event, and you cannot use `.off()` if you did not use `.on()` to bind the event:

```
$(function(jQuery) {
    (function($) {
        $(".showlist-wrap").on('hover', function() {
            $(".showlist-artwork,.showlist-info",this).toggle().off("hover");
        });
    })( jQuery );
});
```

Or the content you're binding this event handler to may not be available at `DOM ready`:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('hover', ".showlist-wrap", function() {
        $(".showlist-artwork,.showlist-info",this).toggle().off("hover");
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the second one did the trick. I need to read up on DOM ready.

Comment: Nope, the second one doesn't work any more as of 2023. It just generates a syntax error about a missing '{'.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress autoloads the jquery, so if you included the jquery manually in your theme the jquery is loaded twice and this could create a conflict.

Please read [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/) article about including js and css properly

Comment: No I'm not loading jQuery twice. I'm using the bundled enqueued versions of both jQuery & migrate. Only one instance of each, being enqueued correctly.